# How to create a dynamically created macro with optional argument?

Tags: macros, programming

The following MWE does not compile (unfortunately). The objective is to create a dynamically created macro, for example, `\Newton` with an optional argument.

If `\Newton` is invoked, `$F=ma$` will be rendered. If `\Newton[$F=GMm/r^2$]` is invoked then `$F=GMm/r^2$` rather than `$F=ma$` will be rendered.

How to implement this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
    \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname[1][]{%
        % if ##1 is given 
        % then use ##1
        % else use #2
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$}

\Newton should produce $F=ma$.

\Newton[$F=GMm/r^2$] replaces $F=ma$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I think I don't need key-value interface because it will make my input file complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
\newcommand{\CreateMacro}[2]{%
  % #1 is the macro name, #2 the default expansion
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1][#2]{##1}%
}
```

Let's see why: `\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$}` would do

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname Newton\endcsname[1][$F=ma$]{#1}
```

and the calls

```
\Newton
\Newton[$F=GMm/r^2$]
```

would produce the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `etoolbox` and a `xparse` version, the `xparse` version is more failsafe regarding empty optional arguments.

The `etoolbox` version uses `\ifblank{...}{true}{false}` to check the optional argument. There's an alternative (but not shorter) with `\notblank`, however.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
  \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname[1][]{%
    \ifblank{##1}{%
      #2%
    }{%
      ##1%
    }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateOtherMacro}{mm}{%
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{o}{%
    \IfValueTF{##1}{%
      ##1%
    }{%
      #2%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$}%
\CreateOtherMacro{Einstein}{$E=mc^2$}%

\Newton\ should produce $F=ma$.

\Newton[$F=GMm/r^2$] replaces $F=ma$.

\Einstein\ should produce $E=mc^2$.

\Einstein[$8\pi G$] will show something different

\end{document}
```